# I can not update the groups in XML

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

It should be noted that in Odoo 15 I don't have this issue.

When I want to update the attribute `groups` in the XML I have the following error:

> `Field 'journal_id' used in context ({..... hes group(s) account.group_account_invoice,account.group_account_readonly.`

I want to update the permission to see the field `journal_id` in the account move form view. But when I install it the first time the module that is overriding the `groups` attribute is working FINE, but when I tried to update the same module I have always the same issue, this brings inconsistency.

This is my current code:

```
<xpath expr="//header//button[@name='button_draft']" position="attributes">
   <attribute name="groups">account.group_account_user</attribute>
</xpath>
```

---

View to override (Invoice form view)

````
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherit_account_move_form_view_for_sp_siat">
            <field name="name">account.move.form: sp siat</field>
            <field name="model">account.move</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_move_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <!--  OVERRIDED    -->
                <xpath expr="//div[@name='journal_div']" position="after">
                    <field name="sp_siat_type_sector_document" string="Documento Electronico" force_save="1"/>
                </xpath>

                <xpath expr="//header//button[@name='button_draft']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="groups">account.group_account_user</attribute>
                </xpath>
             </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
---
The only statement of the journal_id that is using the context is the following:
```XML
<label for="journal_id" groups="account.group_account_readonly" invisible="context.get('default_journal_id') and context.get('move_type', 'entry') != 'entry'"/>
<div name="journal_div" class="d-flex" invisible="context.get('default_journal_id') and context.get('move_type', 'entry') != 'entry'">
    <field name="journal_id" groups="account.group_account_readonly" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" attrs="{'readonly': [('posted_before', '=', True)]}"/>
    <span class="oe_inline o_form_label mx-3" groups="base.group_multi_currency" attrs="{'invisible': [('move_type', '=', 'entry')]}"> in </span>
    <field name="currency_id" groups="base.group_multi_currency" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '!=', 'draft')], 'invisible': [('move_type', '=', 'entry')]}"/>
</div>
````

Comment: Are you sure you've pasted the right XML code here? The xpath is telling us you want to restrict a button to a group. I don't see `journal_id` anywhere.

Comment: @CZoellner yes, that is the problem for some reason I can not override the groups attribute, my intention is to replace some field on this case the `button_draft` (Invoice view form). but there is field on this case `journal_id` that is now allowing to replace the field is throwing that error